# Display data from a database using JSP, Servlets, JSTL and Command Pattern

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, dao, command-pattern

I'm trying to display data from a database, but nothing happens on JSP. I used a design pattern Command. Where is my problem?

Structure of Command design pattern:

[image]

Here is my code:

JSP page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Profile page</title>
</head>
<body>

<table border="0" align="center" class="container" width="80%">

<tr>
<td width="100%" colspan="2" class="logo"><a href="http://localhost:8080/Blog_App/">        <img alt="Logo" src="img/logo.png"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="content">
<div class="edit">

<input type="hidden" name="command" value="view" />
<c:forEach var="item" items="${viewList}">
<c:out value="${item.header}" /><br>
<c:out value="${item.text}" /><br>
</c:forEach>

</div>
</td>

<td class="control">
<div class="reg">

<h3>Hello</h3>
<p>Your Profile</p>
</div>
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" class="about">
<span class="copyright">&#169 Stark, 2013 </span><a href="about.jsp">О проекте</a>
</td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

My Controller:

```
package com.stark.controller;

//imports

@WebServlet("/controller")
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

RequestHelper requestHelper = RequestHelper.getInstance();

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)         throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");

    String page = null;
    try{
        Command command = requestHelper.getCommand(request);
        page = command.execute(request, response);
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(page);
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}

}
```

My RequestHelper:

```
package com.stark.controller;

//imports

public class RequestHelper {

public static RequestHelper instance = null;
HashMap<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<String, Command>();

private RequestHelper(){
    commands.put("reg", new RegCommand());
    commands.put("login", new LoginCommand());
    commands.put("edit", new EditCommand());
    commands.put("view", new ViewCommand());
    System.out.println("Helper Works");
}

public Command getCommand(HttpServletRequest request){
    String action = request.getParameter("command");
    Command command = commands.get(action);
    if(command == null){
        command = new NoCommand();
    }
    return command;
}

public static RequestHelper getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new RequestHelper();
    }
    return instance;
}
}
```

My Interface Command:

```
package com.stark.command;

//imports

public interface Command {
public String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException;
}
```

My ViewCommand:

```
package com.stark.command;

//imports

public class ViewCommand implements Command{

@Override
public String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");

    System.out.println("View Command Works");

    String page = null;

    HttpSession ses = request.getSession();
    String username = (String) ses.getAttribute("username");

    ViewLogic viewLogic = new ViewLogic();

    List<Posts> viewList = new ArrayList<Posts>(); 
    viewList = viewLogic.getPostsList(username);
    request.setAttribute("viewList", viewList);

    page = "/profile.jsp";

    return page;
}

}
```

My ViewLogic:

```
package com.stark.logic;

//imports

public class ViewLogic {

public List<Posts> getPostsList(String username){
    System.out.println("Logic View Check");
    int author_id = 0;
    List<Posts> viewList = new ArrayList<Posts>();

    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername(username);

    UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
    author_id = userDAO.checkID(user);

    PostsDAO postsDAO = new PostsDAO();
    viewList = postsDAO.viewPosts(author_id);

    return viewList;
}

}
```

And my postsDAO:

```
package com.stark.dao;

//imports

public class PostsDAO {

private Connection con = null;
private PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
private ResultSet rs = null;

public PostsDAO(){
    con = DBConnection.getConnection();
}

public void addPost(int id, Posts posts){
    try {
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO posts (author_id, header,  text) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        pstmt.setInt(1, id);
        pstmt.setString(2, posts.getHeader());
        pstmt.setString(3, posts.getText());
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            pstmt.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}

public List<Posts> viewPosts(int author_id){
    List<Posts> viewList = new ArrayList<Posts>();
    try {
        System.out.println("Check 1");
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT posts.header, posts.text FROM posts WHERE author_id = ?;");
        pstmt.executeQuery();
        rs = pstmt.getResultSet();
        while(rs.next()){
            Posts posts = new Posts();
            posts.setHeader(rs.getString("header"));
            posts.setText(rs.getString("text"));
            viewList.add(posts);
            System.out.println(rs.getString("header") + rs.getString("text"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return viewList;
}

}
```

Comment: thanks for putting effort in, but is there a way you can make the question somewhat more specific? +1 for the obvious effort anyhow.

Comment: The main problem is that my class ViewCommand is not called

Comment: I strongly recommend using a debugger in cases like this (that's that they are made for).

Comment: And in which JSP do you call the controller, there is not `form` in your JSP.

Comment: <form action="controller" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="command" value="view" />
<c:forEach var="item" items="${viewList}">
 <c:out value="${item.header}" /><br>
 <c:out value="${item.text}" /><br>
</c:forEach>
</form>

Comment: I added this, but form need to submit. how to make the form itself submited?

Comment: there was a message in the log: INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found error in my PostsDAO:

```
public List<Posts> viewPosts(int author_id){
    System.out.println(author_id);
    List<Posts> viewList = new ArrayList<Posts>();
    try {
        System.out.println("Check 1");
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT posts.header, posts.text FROM posts WHERE author_id = ?;");
//I forgot set parameter for ?
        pstmt.setInt(1, author_id);
        pstmt.executeQuery();
        rs = pstmt.getResultSet();
        while(rs.next()){
            Posts posts = new Posts();
            posts.setHeader(rs.getString(1));
            posts.setText(rs.getString(2));
            viewList.add(posts);
            System.out.println(rs.getString("header") + rs.getString("text"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return viewList;
}
```

And in my JSP page I added  tag, but it's works when I press the submit button. How to make autosubmited form?

JSP code:

```
<form action="controller" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="command" value="view" />
<c:forEach var="item" items="${viewList}">
<c:out value="${item.header}" /><br>
<c:out value="${item.text}" /><br>
</c:forEach>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```